# «Il me l'a acheté» ou «il l'a acheté pour moi»

Tags: prépositions, syntaxe

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence de sens entre ces deux phrases ou est-ce que l'une des deux a l'air plus naturelle?

1. Il me l'a acheté.
2. Il l'a acheté pour moi.

Mon idée, c'est que (1) va bien mais aussi que c'est ambigu puisque ce ne serait pas clair si le *me* est le vendeur ou la personne qui reçoit l'objet.

De plus, s'il y a une différence, est-ce que ça s'applique à d'autres phrases? Par exemple:

3. Cela m'est important.
4. C'est important pour moi.
5. Cela m'est difficile.
6. C'est difficile pour moi.
7. Elle me prépare un repas.
8. Elle prépare un repas pour moi.

Comment: _Ce m'est important_ et _ce m'est difficile_ ne se disent pas. On peut dire: _cela m'est important_ et _cela m'est difficile_, mais c'est un peu boîteux.

Answer (score 2):

*Il l'a acheté pour moi* met en relief la personne à qui est destiné l'achat. Suivant le contexte, *il me l'a acheté* sera sans doute compris sans ambiguïté, et aura le même sens que *il l'a acheté pour moi*. La différence est vraiment une nuance d'emphase.

Attention, dans les exemples 3-8, 3 et 5 ne s'utilisent pas. On utiliserait plutôt *cela* (ou *ça* (voir le commentaire de jlliagre)) à la place de *ce*.

Comment: Aussi ***ça** m'est difficile/important*, en particulier à l'oral. Les formes avec *cela/ça* étaient apparemment [plus courantes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7a+m%27est+difficile%2Bcela+m%27est+difficile%2Cc%27est+difficile+pour+moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) que la forme avec *pour moi* aux siècles derniers.

Comment: @jlliagre Incorporé à ma réponse avec attribution :-)

Answer (score 0):

"Il me l'a acheté." = il l'a acheté **à moi**. (on dit acheter quelque chose à quelqu'un). Dans ce cas, tu vas t'en servir de ce qu'il t'a acheté.

Ex : il m'a acheté une voiture = il a acheté une voiture à moi

---

"Il l'a acheté pour moi" = ce qu'on t'a acheté va faire effet sur toi (tu vas le subir)

Ex: Il a acheté un médicament pour moi = (pour mon bien)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).